# Truncating a memory mapped file

Tags: c++, file, memory, boost

I am currently using Boost.Iostreams to memory map multiple files for writing out very large data sets. The amount of data to be written varies with a guarantee that it will not exceed a predefined limit. Usually the full capacity of the mapped file is used but sometimes it is not, with only a very small portion being written.

My issue is that I do not know beforehand the amount of data to be written, so each memory mapped file is created with an equal size. As a result the program is less efficient as the files that have not been used to their full capacity are zero filled upon closing.

Is there a way of truncating the file before closing using Boost.Iostreams or another cross platform library (preferably boost)?

I know there are other similar questions but I don't believe they offer a cross platform solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `truncate(2)` or the `ftruncate(2)` system call to truncate the size of an existing file.

Note, that use should `munmap()`  the file, before truncating in. If you review the contents of the `mmap(2)` man page, it documents that truncating an mmap-ed file is undefined behavior.

But, `munmap()`ing the file before truncating it should not break any rules.

Comment: Thanks for the info but will these work with files currently mapped using Boost.Iostreams? I'm really after a cross platform solution but if this is compatible then I can just write a wrapper with _chsize for windows.

Comment: I am not familiar with the Boost library. truncate() works with any regularly-opened file descriptor. You will have to do whatever needs to be done in order to unmap the file. I'm sure that Boost must provide you with the means of obtaining the underlying file descriptor.

Comment: It looks as if Boost.Iostreams only supports fixed sized memory mapped files and cannot give a file descriptor. I'll have to write a wrapper to handle things on both unix and windows systems using mmap, mumap and ftruncate. Thanks for the help.